# Angular FormGroup: .setValue methold is not updating the field

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have the following html

```
<form [formGroup]="form_sample" class="form">

                <div class="float-container">

                    <div class="float-child">
                        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="form_sample.get('sample').valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'">
                            <label for="sample">Sample</label>
                            <bb-select2 class="validate" formControlName="sample" id="sample" [data]="samples$  | async" [idKey]="'uuid'" [textKey]="'name'" [width]="'100%'" [placeholder]="'Select a sample ...'" (select)="form_sample.get('sample').setValue($event)"></bb-select2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <ng-container *ngIf="form_sample.get('active')">
                    <div class="tagToggle">
                        <input id="activeToggle" class="tgl" type="checkbox" [formControl]="form_sample.get('active')">
                        <label for="activeToggle" class="tgl-btn"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Active
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
                <!--Hidden button in case user press Enter-->
                <button *ngIf="form_sample.valid" [hidden]="true" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close($event)"></button>
            </form>
```

with a form control called sample (a uuid).

[image]

If the user set a value for sample and navigate back to the page the control is empty.

[image]

I would like to restore the control value if a value has been already selected when navigating back. The following code does not work:

```
if (this.runCreated) {
                console.log(this.runCreated);
                this.form_sample.controls['sample'].setValue(this.runCreated['sample']);
            }
```

Comment: what is `runCreated` and when is that `if` called? Is the component destroyed when you navigate?  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Run created is just a json object containing the sample uuid: e.g. sample: "a4173018-afcd-4d58-8363-051a77e64f7d"

Comment: OK, and where is that last piece of code executed, currently the code presented is not reproducible, there is not enough code to for example test your code in a stackblitz.

Comment: The component is on a modal in a section that is made visible or not using an *ngIf

Comment: OK, still not enough information, we cannot guess what your code looks like ;)